# I have Created a Search Page and when the Data is Binding I am Getting Stack OverFlow Error..I dont know Why it is appearing

Tags: c#

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    String mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("UspSearch", sqlconn);

    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtApplicationNumber.Text.Trim()))
        sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationNumber", txtApplicationNumber.Text);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    sqlconn.Open();

    da.Fill(dt);

    sqlconn.Close();

    gvSearch.DataSource = dt;

    BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: Have you debug the code? Try checking the line of exception

Comment: What did you try, I can guess nothing, and could you take a time when you are posting a question. That means you should tell us what's the error, what did you try, and your question shouldn't be in a title, so could you edit the question please?

Comment: I debugged the code and error is occuring in data Fill..How to use Line of exception

Comment: Please fix the code formatting and remove the comment clutter.

Comment: What does UspSearch return. What are the fields? Is it the arithmetic overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your recursion leads to the overflow.

In the last line of your method you call the method just again. This will never end until your program collapses.

Comment: Thanks alot..I tried the same Yesterday by Placing it in Comments and Now I just removed that Line..Amazing its working..Thanks again